# Amend cross sections for single element

Tags: kdb

I'm playing around with an example on https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/#cross-sections

```
$ q
KDB+ 3.6 2019.04.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems
q)d:((1 2 3;4 5 6 7);(8 9;10;11 12);(13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20))
q)i:(2 0; 0 1 0)
q)y:(100 200 300; 400 500 600)
q)r:.[d; i; ,; y]
```

It all works fine except if I'll try to reference a single element d[1;1]:

```
q)i:(1 0; 0 1 0)
q)r:.[d; i; ,; y]
'type
  [0]  r:.[d; i; ,; y]
```

But if I use join `,` for lists and for just single element it works as supposed:

```
q)10,200
10 200
q)10,((),200)
10 200
```

So why the amend operation breaks on this simple join?

Upd:

One more example:

```
q)@[(1; 2; 3);1;,;10]
'type
  [0]  @[(1; 2; 3);1;,;10]
       ^
```

but it's ok if one use lists:

```
q)@[(1; (),2; 3);1;,;10]
1
2 10
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in examining the data you are extracting to join, here the operator `-3!` is your friend to help reveal the actual structure through multiple layers of enlistment

```
q)d:((1 2 3;4 5 6 7);(8 9;10;11 12);(13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20))
q)i1:(2 0; 0 1 0)
q)i2:(1 0; 0 1 0)
q)y:(100 200 300; 400 500 600)
q)-3!r1:.[d; i1]
"((13 14;15 16 17 18;13 14);(1 2 3;4 5 6 7;1 2 3))"
q)q){type each x} each .[d; i1]
7 7 7
7 7 7
q)-3!r2:.[d; i2]
"((8 9;10;8 9);(1 2 3;4 5 6 7;1 2 3))"
q){type each x} each .[d; i2]
7 -7 7
7 7  7
```

No here we can see that in the first case, each element of `r1` is a list of lists, but for `r2` the first element is 2 lists of longs with an atomic long `10`.

From the cross section documentation

> The shape of y is 2 3, the same shape as the cross-section selected by d . i

i.e., Shape should be the counts and types matching, the type of each item of y is a 7h, that should match the type of each selection from d.

Essentially when you are using the amendment operators `,` and `@` it will be expecting conformity as it is using an amend in place. `a:1;a,:1 2 3` will also fail.

We can confirm this with your other examples

```
q)type @[(1; (),2; 3);1]
7h
```

Changing that example to adjust the first element

```
q)@[(1; (),2; 3);0;,;10]
'type
```

The reason that just using the `,` operator as `10,((),200)` didn't cause any errors, is because you are using it outside the amend overloads, within the amend overload `,` is expecting to be working with matching shape. When used directly it can promote and adjust shape.

Comment: Thank you! The words about expecting confirmity => amend in place happened are brilliant. But as for the type of each `y` item, they are all -7, not 7: `{type each x} each y`. According to this we shoud expect all items in `d.i` to be of type -7h, right?

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation I can offer is that kdb+ tries to use amend-in-place (also known as [assignment through the operator](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#colon)) when it can.

For example, this works:

```
q)l:(13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20)
q)l[1],:200
q)l
13 14
15 16 17 18 200
19 20
```

But this doesn't:

```
q)l:(8 9;10;11 12)
q)l[1],:200
'type
[0]  l[1],:200
       ^
```

The latter fails because kdb can't substitute the *vector* `10 200` for the *atom* `10` -- changing types is not something that amend-in-place is supposed to do.

If you used your own function `{x,y}` instead of the plus *operator* the second
expression from your example would work as expected too because kdb will *replace* existing values with return values of the function (which, in contrast to the built-in `,`, is a black box as far as kdb is concerned):

```
q)i:(1 0; 0 1 0)
q)r:.[d; i; ,; y]
q).[d; ii; {x,y}; y]
(1 2 3 400 600;4 5 6 7 500)
(8 9 100 300;10 200;11 12)
(13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20)
```